# How to get the correct referrer url in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If you go to http://jsfiddle.net and then come to stackoverflow and then open the console and type:

```
console.log( document.referrer );
```

You get

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
```

instead of

```
http://jsfiddle.net/
```

How can I get `http://jsfiddle.net/` ?

Comment: I think that *is* the correct referrer value - that's the way jsfiddle works. The "result" pane page is in that domain.

Answer (score 6):

You get it because jsfiddle uses frames. Use `window.frames.top.document.referrer` instead.

Comment: Well he's trying to see how to get "jsfiddle.net" from *here* - from stackoverflow, in other words, presumably after clicking on a link in the fiddle.

Comment: Well, you're right. I wasn't paying enough attention to the question :)